# Incrementing NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, nsnumber

So, after I load the animations sprite frames into the cache in the game I'm making, I count how many frames each animation has. I do this because in the game config there's a value for the duration of each animation, and when I create the CCAnimation, the delay attr is AnimationDuration/FramesAmount.

To count the amount of frames per animation, I open the animations.plist and iterate the entries getting every key, removing the file name, and storing every frame (as key) in a NSMutableDictionary with the amount as an NSNumber that I update through the iteration. The thing is that I don't like how I need to get the NSNumber intValue, do +1, and then alloc another NSNumber and re set the value for the key. Is there any better way of doing this?? Thanks all! (like.. in php OR JS would be dictonary[frame]++)

Here is the code:

```
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"animations.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];

NSMutableDictionary *conf = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSDictionary *frames = [plistData valueForKey:@"frames"];

NSNumber *amount;
for( int i=0; i < [frames count]; i++ ) {
    NSString *frame = [[frames allKeys] objectAtIndex:i];

    NSRange range = [frame rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    frame = [frame substringToIndex:range.location];

    if( [conf objectForKey:frame] == nil )
        amount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
    else
        amount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[conf objectForKey:frame] intValue]+1];//amount++...

    [conf setObject:amount forKey:frame];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an NSNumber you can create a MyNumber object with an int/long whatever in it and a property to access the number without having to do the whole alloc thing every time you change it. Could even have an addTo method.

Comment: Cool, thanks, it's kinda an ugly hack but I think it's better than what I have now.

Comment: @Spiegel -- What do you think an NSNumber is, "under the covers"?  It's just another object class (well, actually a family of classes) -- invented not because it's somehow a super-efficient implementation but because a number of different other interfaces required an object that represents a number, and it's good to have a standard one vs each new use inventing its own.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with NSNumbers, there is no other way than to get its integer value, increment it and put it back in your NSNumber.

But why start out with an NSNumber in the first place? Why not start with an int, do your magic and put that int in your NSNumber instance?

To show you what I mean:

```
int myCounterAsInt = 0;
for (...loopcondition..)
{
    myCounterAsInt++;
}

NSNumber *myCounterAsNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myCounterAsInt];
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your suggestion, how would you do it?

Comment: I don't think that would work. I'm iterating a dictionary with every frame from every animation, and I don't know if the frames for one animation will be always grouped together, so, I need to check the frame in every iteration and then asign it to the proper object in the conf dictionary

Comment: Ah, I see. Then it is indeed not possible. An NSDictionary can only hold objects, not primitives. You always have to wrap your primitives in objects to be able to insert them in your collection...